# Swift iOS app - statically assigning table properties with dynamically changing rows

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, dynamic, storyboard

I am very new to iOS programming. I am trying to develop a table that has the always has 2 sections (this is the static part), but the labels need to be able to change what section they are in dynamically. Here's an example:

**Section 1**

- Item name 1
- Item name 2
- Item name 3

**Section 2**

- Item name 4
- Item name 5
- Item name 6

At any given time (dictated by my code), any item can switch from Section 1 from Section 2 or vice versa, in real-time, i.e. they can change while the user is looking at the table. This would require a visible change in the size of both sections.

Unfortunately I do not have code to show, because I'm not quite sure where to start. All I have is a UITableView in my storyboard. I set the "Content" property to Dynamic Prototypes, but I want the number of sections to be static, and I can't find a way to specify that. I looked through the documentation and found numberOfSections(), which only *returns* the section count. Has anybody done something similar before? Thanks.

Comment: You should set the `datasource` for the table view, and implement the relevant [UITableViewDataSource methods](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple's documentation is your best friend in iOS programming! You can use the numberOfSections() to return the number of sections which in your case seems to be 2. The cellForRowAtIndexPath method is where the magic happens in a UITableView. Here you have the indexPath variable that you can use to locate your data and place it where you want it. If your data for the Table View is in an array, you can access it and arrange it using [indexPath.row] or [indexPath.section]. I know it seems like it is super hard and confusing, but the best way to figure out how to do this is to experiment. There are many ways to do the same thing, so read some of Apple's documentation (you can find this in Xcode, look at some sample code from YouTube, this website etc., and experiment! Good luck :)

UPDATE:
Ok so here is how you can accomplish this. Feel free to change things however you see fit :)

#### Setting Up Cell Data

Okay, so the best way to be able to change the data dynamically is to use a multidimensional array (don't worry, it is fairly easy to use one!)
For example:

```
var tableData = [["1st sec1", "first sec2"], ["2nd sec1", "2nd sec2"]]
```

To specify the number of sections in your table view you can use:

```
override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
     return tableData.count
```

This will return the number of arrays that are in our multidimensional array, in this case there are two.

So then to specify the number of rows in each section, use:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSectionsection: Int) -> Int {
     return tableData[section].count
}
```

This will return the number of items in the individual arrays in our multidimensional one, defined by "section" which is provided in the parameters of the function.

Now, I am not entirely sure where you are going to be deciding when data gets moved from one section to another in your code, but wherever you decide to do that, you can use this to move data around in the multidimensional array:

```
var dataToMove = tableData[0][1]
// in this example, dataToMove will have a value of "first sec2"
tableData[0].removeAtIndex(1)
// this will remove "first sec2" from the array
tableData[1].append(dataToMove)
// this will place "first sec2" into the second section of the array
```

Okay, so once you are done with the hard part, you can customize the cells:

```
// put this code in cellForRowAtIndexPath:
let cellTitle = tableData[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
// after this, just set the title of the cell to the cellTitle variable, and you're set!
```

#### Naming TableView Sections

This is the quick and dirty way to name the sections of the TableView:
So first you need to make an array (it can be a normal one this time :) )

```
let sectionTitles = ["First Section", "Second Section"]
```

Then use this function to set the section titles:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
     if section < sectionTitles.count {
         return sectionTitles[section]
     }

     return nil
}
```

Now we could have just put: return sectionTitles[section], but if there was a section that we didn't have a title for, the app would have crashed, so this way if there is no title for the section in the array, the title of it will be blank.

I hope I was able to help you!!

Comment: Thanks! I actually just figured out the [indexPath.row] method of getting the appropriate labels, but I still have one section as opposed to two. Ignoring the part about them dynamically changing in real time, how can I place each label within its own section? Right now my storyboard shows that I have one section; do I add the second section in storyboard or do I do that programatically?

Comment: I actually have one more question that I'm still unclear on. There are a bunch of these tableView() functions (amongst others) that have different parameters and what not. Do all of these functions get called periodically as data changes? Or do they get called once at the beginning? I'm not sure how they get utilized exactly.

Comment: These functions get called when the tableView is loaded onto the view. To call them again when data is changed etc. you can use tableView.reloadData() and it will update itself

Comment: Got it. Thanks again!